# How to overlay video over webcam streaming using opencv or ffmpeg in Java

Tags: java, opencv, video, video-capture, vp8

In my project I am previewing webcam capture and video (in `webm` format with `vp8` codecs) capture on the screen in Java Desktop application. Currently I use `VideoCapture` class to retrieve both webcam and video frames perform some drawings on the frames and then show them to the user. I would like to place video over webcam capture as my video has alpha channel. So I am retrieving each frame of the video and webcam as OpenCV Mat and then try to overlay mat over each other. However I get error because retrieving Mat from trainer capture removes the alpha channel. What is the best alternative to `VideoCapture` class to work with video frame by frame and be able to retrieve frame as OpenCV Mat?